# Changing http status during streaming rendering (renderToNodeStream)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http

I try to implement streaming rendering.
Whats I am doing now is:

```
// it is example code
res.write(htmlHeader)
const renderingStream = renderToNodeStream(<App />);
renderingStream.pipe(res)
renderingStream.on('end', () => {
 res.end();
});

// I am tracking error a bit differently, it is just example
renderingStream.on('error', () => {
  res.status(500);
});
```

And as far I know, http status in express.js has to be set before we send anything to the client.
It means, if I send html header section first, (to pre-fetch assets during rendering) it means I am not able to change http status code to anything else then 200?

Is it posiblity to change http status during rendering after header section will be send?
If not, how people dealing with http statuses if they decide for streaming rendering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the http spec says that the first step in responding to the client is by writing headers and then start writing the body of the response.

when you call res.write you tell nodejs implicitly to write headers then start writing your stuff.

i guess you cannot do what you want.
The client need to determine by itself that the body is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

So if it is not possible it means that renderingToNodeStream or streaming rendering itself isn't SEO friendly?